# How to mediate a SWF-Flashfile using a PHP mediating a.k.a. HTTP-Pseudostreaming script?

Tags: php, html, flash, http, mediator

I'm writing a simple small context media platform. It is mainly based on so called HTTP Pseudostreaming, where I mediate the media file using a php script. This is used for checking access to the file, and for linking to the correct directory. In the following the basic parts of my code:

```
// [...]

header("Content-type: " . $file_type);
header("Content-length: " . $file_size);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file_name);
header("Expires: " . gmdate ("D, d M Y H:i:s", (time () + $_CFG['FILE_EXPIRE_TIME']))); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate ("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime($file_path)));  

$file_handle = fopen($file_path, "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
      print(fread($file_handle, FILETRANSFER_BUFFER_SIZE));
}
fclose($file_handle); 

// [...]
```

Currently i use this script to relay mp3, flv, mp4, pdf and image formats. This works pretty good. Furthermore i wanted to add Flash support (swf). However the file gets transferred. The HTTP Header that is sent by the server also seems to be okay:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 08:49:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9 with
Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9
Expires: Thu, 07 Feb 2013 08:49:16
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0,
pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-length: 28869
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SWFTest1.swf
Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Feb 2012 08:31:00
Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash
```

The only problem is: if I want to play this flash file from Browser (independent from Browsertype) it doesn't work. The flasharea stays blank. If I link directly to the same .swf file it works. If I download using my relaying script and play the flashfile locally: It works.

My calling DHTML/JavaScript lines are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

<div style="margin: 5px;" id="flashcontent"></div>                              
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s1 = new SWFObject("file.php?id=236&type=media", "flashfile", "480", "360", "7");
    s1.addVariable("width","480");
    s1.addVariable("height","360");
    s1.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I would install http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to see what was going on.

Comment: No, I don't get any error message. I use something similar to CharlesProxy, where i get the header that i've posted from. It correctly downloads the file but it simply doesn't play.

Comment: @nemcija when you replace `file.php?id=236&type=media` by `SWFTest1.swf` does the play

Comment: As I've written: "If I link directly to the same .swf file it works."

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SWFTest1.swf` is the header causing problem. Since Flash 10.0.2, its presence prevent the loading of the SWF for security reason.

Reference : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes.html#head32